# Showing images of an Actor changing in time as Animating

Tags: html5-canvas

I am trying to animate 4 images of an actor but what i am seeing is only one image and no other change.

```
function init()
{
i=0;
while(i<ActStandX.length) //ActStandX holds the x locations of actor in a image spritesheet
{
    for(var currentFrame=0;currentFrame<10;currentFrame++)
    {
       ctxBg.clearRect(0,0,800,600); //ctxBg is 2d context  of canvas
       ctxBg.drawImage(img,ActStandX[i],10,actWidth,actHeight,200,300,60,110);
            }
    i++;
}
requestAnimFrame(init); 
}
```

i have tried this code so far but no success.

Comment: You are drawing each image over the previous, without giving the browser a chance to paint in between drawing each image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var i = 0;

function init()
{
    ctxBg.clearRect(0,0,800,600);
    ctxBg.drawImage(img,ActStandX[i++],10,actWidth,actHeight,200,300,60,110);

    if (i == ActStandX.length) i = 0; // loop the animation

    requestAnimFrame(init); 
}
```

Note that it will change frames every time it paints, so it may be faster than you actually want. It isn't hard to limit the incrementation of `i` based on the time passed, I'm sure you can figure it out. :)

Comment: Thank you for helping i found the solution..
as you said in comment that was the problem.
Anyways thanks..